# How to mount an encrypted FreeNAS dataset on Linux?

Tags: linux, nas, zfs, freenas

I am running a FreeNAS rig using 6 hard drives and ZFS with activated Geli-encryption.

Since I want to transition to Linux, I want to ask how I can open the Dataset on Linux - apparently there seems no obvious way to do it.

Does someone have an idea how I could nevertheless use my drives with Linux?

Comment: Looks like there’s no way. I found this [proof of concept](https://emergent.unpythonic.net/01385778545), but it seems abandoned.

Comment: GELI (FreeBSD) and LUKS (Linux) are not on-disk compatible. It might be possible to do what you want if you can coax the actual key material and algorithm specifications out of the FreeBSD side, and use those directly with dm-crypt with losetup mapped devices (for offsets) on the Linux side. I do not recommend that as a permanent solution, but it might be possible to get access to the data that way enough to import the pool and rewrite the devices as LUKS devices (assuming you have redundancy).